# Ps4 strange behavior, failure to identify control - error code CE-30993-4

Tags: ps4, hardware

Hello my ps4 is having trouble identifying a wifi control, before anything else, this control has been tested on another console, and the problem also occurs with the other control I have, so the possibility of being the control is discarded.

So, what happens when the console goes into standby mode and turns ON, which it stops identifying the wifi control, and the control light blinks several times.

It also happened when I connected to a wifi network, so I only use a LAN cable.

Even turning it off and on or with a restart or any control reset as well.

Another problem is that when you turn the ps4 blinks a white light for more than 5 minutes until it actually shuts off.

### What makes it work again:

"Initialisation of PS4", then turning it off, pulling it off (wait more than 10 min), and turning it back on

It works again, and I play normally without using standby mode connected to the network cable.

Although it did not make sense to wait 10 mins, that was what actually worked.

Accidentally when it goes into standby I have to do the whole process again, download all the games, and restore the psn plus saves.

A palliative solution was to turn off the standby mode, I would like help to solve this problem.

Even if I go back to normal doing all this, maybe it's a hardware problem?

Thank you.

---

### Edit: found the error code:  **CE-30993-4**

I was able to search for this error in google:

https://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/PS4/CE-30993-4-Error-code/td-p/25083687#thread-replies

**Hotpocket266**, replied:

Guys, I had the same problem and I found the solution!!! I will tell you exactly how I did it

- Step 1: turned on ps4
- step 2: If you have a psvita registered to the ps4 access from their
  into the home page of the ps4
- Step 2: if you do not have a ps vita continue to follow the process.
- Step 3: Turn on  All Controllers even if unable to sync to ps4 system
- Step 4: Grab anything close to a paper clip and stick it into the
  tiny hole near the L2 Button under controller for 10 seconds on only ONE of the controllers
- Step 5: With care pull the cable from the back of the ps4 off the
  system
- Step 6: After a few moments put back the cables into the ps4 system
  then turn it on
- Step 7: After the system reboots itself completely it will ask to
  push the ps button and hooray:

!!!!!THIS WORKED!!!!!

As seen by other answers in this forum ppl took for repair the bluetooth/wifi and don't solve, seems the be a bug or something (software)

*And I'll leave this thread open, because I'm looking for a definitive solution, this may happen again.*

Comment: This does sound like a pretty serious hardware issue. Have you spoken to PS Support about it?

Comment: yes!! they dont have a solution, they say restart ps4/controller, reset, etc..etc.. helpdesk default speach. haha

Answer (score 2):

### The fix

I know this is an old question, but since it's one of the highest search results on Google, I thought I may add my experience with this problem. This error code means there's a problem with the Bluetooth receiver in your PS4. It doesn't necessarily mean it's fried tho, so don't panic just yet. First, turn off your PS4 completely, which means you don't want to put it in Rest Mode, but power off completely. Once it's off, pick your Dualshock, and reset it by inserting a needle or a match into the little hole at the back of the controller, until you feel the button inside, and keep it pressed for 5 seconds. Leave your console off for a few minutes, and then turn it on using the power button on the console. Plug in your Dualshock to the USB cable and press the PS button when asked by the console. Once logged in, try unplugging the USB cable and check if your controller is still working. If it is, then your problem's solved but keep reading, if it doesn't, then you may repeat previous steps, but leave your console off for a longer time, say 30 minutes. If that won't help you either, then I'm afraid your Bluetooth receiver is dead and you have to repair your console.

### To not let this happen again

Now, if you've managed to get it working again, please make sure your console is properly ventilated. The reason it stopped working for me was the heat. If you don't take action to ensure your PS4 has proper air circulation you will encounter this problem again and again until it actually kills your Bluetooth receiver and/or wifi adaptor. If your PS4 makes a loud noise, it means it's overheating

Comment: I still have this problem, I will try this latter.. but I tried everything .. YES..I said everything... I dont want o fix this console because its to expensive... but I'm playing by remote play in my notebook using USB

Comment: This solution that I posted, worked for a few weeks, and started to not connect to my controller

Comment: Well, if you still experience it, then I am afraid it's a hardware problem - Bluetooth Receiver specifically. I'm glad you've found a way to keep playing, but the only real solution at this point is to take your console for a repair.

Answer (score -1):

It is a software issue they have been having them since I bought my new one in 2019.

From the very first day I've had WiFi problems and then my Bluetooth not connecting to my controller. This only happens part of the time when the PS4 goes into standby mode by itself, or when it gets ready to go into power-saving mode - then the controller will not reconnect until I turn it all off and back on.

Do not put power-saving settings on, or let PS4 controllers go off by themselves - it is a software issue that Playstation has to fix.